# Find out if it is possible to plot a datetime xaxis into a given axis

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot, matlab-figure

I have a matlab function that plots a `(datetime, double)` series onto a provided axis `plotAxis`. However if `plotAxis` already contains a `(double, double)` series, then you get an error:

> 'Data inputs must match the axis configuration. A numeric axis must
>   have numeric data inputs or data inputs which can be converted to
>   double.'

I know that I can query  `plotAxis.XAxis` and find out if it is a `DatetimeRuler` or `NumericRuler`. If it is the former, then I can go ahead and plot, else if it is the latter, then I can fail gracefully. However, it seems that the default type of the `XAxis` property for new axes is also `NumericRuler` and in this case you can plot `datetime` on it (presumably becuase there are no other existing `(double, double)` series plotted).

Is there a general way, given an axes object to find out if a `(datetime, double)` can be plotted on it (other than, of course, a `try`/`catch` block)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you describe it (and as far as I tested) the class of the ruler is not what to look for. The class can be `NumericRuler` for a new plot not containing any data. This ruler then accepts `datetime` data without problems. However, when the axes contain non-`datetime` data on the horizontal axis, then the `NumericRuler` will not play nicely with the other data type and throw an error. Therefore, testing the ruler type is not the way to go.

I suggest testing the data type(s) already contained in the `XData` of the axes' `Children`:

```
ax = gca;
if all(cellfun(@(x) isempty(x) || isdatetime(x.XData), {ax.Children}))
    % Ok to plot datetime
else
    % Not ok to plot datetime, it will throw an error
end
```

This tests either of two conditions:

1. The axes' `Children` are empty, i.e., there are no graphics in the axes. Therefore, `datetime` data can be plotted.
2. Alls the axes' `Children` are of type `datetime`, hence plotting more `datetime` data is possible.

The use of `{ax.Children}` in a `cell` is because the axes' `Children` may not fit into one regular array, because they are of different types or dimensions.

Comment: That;s exactly what I was looking for - ax.Children and child.XData, thanks